# Cannot click React-router Link when it is styled with a particular font

Tags: reactjs, react-router, font-face

So styling the second `li` with a font gives it the right appearance, but prevents `Link` from making a link I can click.

```
renderLinks(){
     if (this.props.authenticated) {
          return [
              <li key="1" className="user-info" >
                  {this.props.email}
              </li>,
              <li key="2" className="sign-out">
                  <Link to="signout">Sign Out</Link>
              </li>
          ]
        } else {
            return [
                ...
            ]
    }
}
```

and my CSS...

```
.sign-out {
    text-decoration: none;
    //font: 10pt 'KnockoutHTF34JuniorSumo';
}
```

If I comment out the font rule, like above, I get a working `Link`. But if I use the font, I can't click the link (even though the anchor tag seems to be present in the DOM)

[image]

What is going on?

Even inline styling breaks the `Link`

[image]

Comment: apply this inline style `style={{fontFamily: 'KnockoutHTF34JuniorSumo'}}` directly on link instead of on `li`, i am using the same and its working as expected :)

Comment: I did that and tried it again. No joy. Still not clickable.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case [here](http://www.webpackbin.com/4Jtk5eTOz) but it seems to work fine(Check the `li` in the `Page1` component). Could you perhaps create a jsfiddle or a webpackbin and reproduce the error.

Comment: check this fiddle i used the styling and its working: https://fiddle.jshell.net/nttgs197/

Comment: thank you all... I narrowed it down to the choice of fonts. Certain fonts screw up the click functionality - others don't. Which is just as mysterious! Ever heard of something like that? All the webfonts I'm using are converted from ttf or otf. That would be hard to reproduce in a fiddle.